# How to create multiple notifications in Kotlin in foreground service

Tags: android, kotlin, service, push-notification

I am working on a parental control app which notify parent multiple times but when I try to create notification with a background service it generates only one 1.

Here is how I do it:

```
    fun createNotification(parent_name: String, notificationText:String, id: Int){
    val MchannelId = channelId+id.toString()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        val channel = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel(
                MchannelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
        }
        (getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
            channel
        )
    }

    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, TabbedActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        id, notificationIntent, 0
    )
    val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "$MchannelId")
        .setContentTitle("Hi $parent_name")
        .setContentText(notificationText)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_child)
        //.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build()
    startForeground(random_number, notification)
}
```

My Full-Service Class:

```
const val TAG2 = "Child Service"
class ParentService: Service() {

val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private val channelId = "Notification from Service"
var parent_name = userName
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

//OnBind Function Implementation
init {
    Log.d(TAG2, "Started Service!")
}

//onCreate Method Implementation

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

}

//OnStartCommand Override
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Thread{
        while (true){
            checkStatus()
            Thread.sleep(PARENT_CHECK_TIME)
        }
    }.start()
    return START_STICKY
}

private fun checkStatus() {
    var listOfNames = ""
    var i = 1
    val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    var list = ArrayList<String>()
    db.collection(LINKED_CHILDS)
        .whereEqualTo(USER_PHONE, userPhone)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents){
                val startTime: Long = calendar.getTimeInMillis()
                val diff = startTime - (document.data[ACTIVE_STATUS] as Long)
                Log.d("TAG", "Time Difference : $diff")
                Log.d("TAG", "${document.data[USER_NAME].toString()}")
                if (diff> MAX_GAP_TIME){
                    Log.d("TAG", "Entered IFF")
                    list.add(document.data[USER_NAME].toString())
                }
            }

            for (name in list){
                listOfNames = listOfNames + "$i. Your child $name is not active\n"
                i++
                createNotification(parent_name, listOfNames, i)
                Log.d("TAG Notification ID:", "ID: $i")
            }
            Log.d("TAG: ", "$listOfNames")

        }
}


fun createNotification(parent_name: String, notificationText:String, id: Int){
    val MchannelId = channelId+id.toString()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        val channel = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel(
                MchannelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
        }
        (getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
            channel
        )
    }

    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, TabbedActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        id, notificationIntent, 0
    )
    val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "$MchannelId")
        .setContentTitle("Hi $parent_name")
        .setContentText(notificationText)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_child)
        //.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build()
    startForeground(id, notification)
}
}
```

Kinldy let me know how I can create multiple Notifications using this background service. Thank You so much in advance!
Kinldy let me know how I can create multiple Notifications using this background service. Thank You so much in advance!
Kinldy let me know how I can create multiple Notifications using this background service. Thank You so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a non-persistent notification, it will show your notifications. The permanent notification will be used for your service to run in the background.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotification() {
        val intent = Intent(this, TabbedActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_child)
            .setContentTitle("Hi $parent_name")
            .setContentText(notificationText)
            .setAutoCancel(true)               
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
            notify(notifManagerId, notification.build())
            notifManagerId++
        }
        parmanentNotification()
    }
```

this is a permanent notification will not be lost and destroyed will keep the service running permanently

```
private fun parmanentNotification() {
        val notification=NotificationCompat.Builder(this,channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_child)
            .setContentTitle("Hi $parent_name")
            .setContentText("Application service running in the background")
            .build()
        startForeground(1,notification)
    }
```

Comment: I hope I was helpful. This works for me. You can design by yourself

Comment: if it worked, can you give 1 vote and hit the tick mark to support

Answer (score 1):

you aren't creating a common `Notification` in this scenario, you are running a `Service`, which must have a foreground representation on screen. So `Activity` visible or sticked, fixed `Notification`, and you are showing it

Now you can have much `Notification`s using similar code, but don't show them using `startForeground`, instead use `NotificationManager`, preferably compat version

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(uniqueId, notification);
```

or just like you are using it already when creating channel inside `if`: `(getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).notify(...)`

foreground-related `Notification` is sticky and lives as long as `Service` works in background, they are "tied". other `Notification`s may be configured to be sticky or swipeable, also should be posted on some own `Channel` (per child? per action?). Note that if you show yet another sticky `Notification` then you have to release it by own through code, just killing `Service` won't dismiss it as it does with foreground-related `Notification`

some [DOC in here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification), read carefully, all answers are there